# VBA Multiple Target.Address (OR) for the Same Action

Tags: excel, vba, list

In a worksheet I have two drop-down lists (cells C7 and C68) which each have a dependent drop-down in the cell below.  I have a code (below) which will clear the cell of the dependent drop-down if I change the selection in the above list (so that the lists do not mis-match), however I can only get this to work for the one drop-down in the sheet.  How can I amend this to that it works if I alter either of the cells with the "Parent" list?

.

Existing code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$C$7" Then
If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
Application.EnableEvents = True
Target.Offset(1, 0).Value = ""
End If
End If
exitHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
```

Comment: Maybe add an OR?

Comment: `If Target.Address = "$C$7" Or Target.Address = "$C$68" Then`...

Comment: You might want to check your first `Application.EnableEvents` as I think you probably should be setting that to `False`, not `True`.

Comment: Thanks all.  I had tried the "or target address" but it wouldn't work, have added this back in and changed the statement from true to false as advised and it works!! Brilliant

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using only 1 dropdown list (which user actually selects) and then 2nd "linked cell" is using vlookup from some kind of data transformation list.

Answer (score 0):

All fixed - for anyone who also has this problem, the correct code was:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$C$7" Or Target.Address = "$C$68" Then
If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Target.Offset(1, 0).Value = ""
End If
End If
exitHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
End Sub
```